# Processes "are run" vs. "are ran"

Tags: grammar

Which is correct?

A concrete example would be:

> These processes (are run|are ran) within the context of this container.

Comment: Only one term in a multi-verb sequence should be modified for tense. That's alrready done with TO BE = ***are***, so TO RUN should remain in the infinitive (but "bare", so it's just ***run***, without ***to***).

Comment: @FF You may wish to delete the above. 'These fairs are hold ...'???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"are run" is correct.

This is a passive voice sentence, form should be " BE + V past participle"

Comment: Please note that ELU is aimed at linguists. Fairly basic questions should be migrated to ELL, not answered. _Very_ basic questions should be close-voted, not answered. Answering such off-topic questions sets an undesirable precedent.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was not aware of ELL's existance, my apologies. How could I go about migrating my question there, if I may ask?

Comment: @KannE Properly asked on ELU.Meta, but I'll answer. It has two; 'Linguistics' is for linguists to address language in general, and foreign languages. But check at 'the tour' here, the 'mission statement'. And check in Meta for the whole debate about why (uniquely, I believe) ELL was established to address more basic but reasonably researched English language questions.

Comment: @KannE There's some very good stuff on ELL. Some of it should be on ELU; it's far above 'basic level'. But ELU tries to maintain scholastic standards and credibility, so GCSE questions or earlier aren't usually appropriate. And school grammars are all too often erroneous.